# How to disable cropping in yith_woocompare plugin in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

Today, I am unable to resolve the issue related to image, I am using yith_woocompare plugin for comparing the products.

In my shop website all the thumbnails and other images are display well, But when somebody wants compare the product then thumbnail is not same as displayed, i think it is automatically cropped by the plugin **yith_woocompare**,

I just want to disable this cropping in yith_woocompare plugin.

For live view : http://csjs.com/shop, After visit the link click on the double arrow icon displayed on the product grid near wishlist.

Answer (score 0):

The option related to image cropping is given by the plugin itself in settings. configure the plugin to see the changes.

The settings that you'll see and need are in the below image.

[image]

Its better to uncheck hard cropping the image.

Lemme know if that resolved your issue.

Comment: After put 140, 220 with Hardcrop unchecked, this is the generated html code  **<img width="140" height="123" alt="Kudrat Di Kala (Part-2)" class="attachment-yith-woocompare-image" src="http://csjs.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/06/Kudrat-Di-Kla-Part-13-176x154.jpg">**  Check with the help of firebug

Comment: After configuration. make sure you regenerate the thumbnails using https://wordpress.org/plugins/regenerate-thumbnails/.

Comment: Okay, I think if i not regenerate the thumbnails, i need to test on some other products that are not in comparing.. ?

Comment: see it picks the width = 140, but not on height that i define in settings